# Control amount of threads reading a file in java (only using synchronized, wait, notify and sleep)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, filereader, synchronized

In the problem I am trying to solve, each thread has to read the whole file, (maybe each thread will deliver its content to another task or any other purpose). After reading it, the thread should sleep a bit then try to read the file again, and only a given number(`n`) of threads should read the file. My attempt to solve this dealing with controling the amount of threads working is in the code below :

```
import java.util.*;

class Reader implements Runnable{

Thread t;
Controler c; 

public Reader(Controler c){
    t = new Thread(this);
    this.c = c;
    t.start();
}


public void run(){
    Random ran = new Random();
    int napTime;

    while(true){
        try{

            w.intentarLeerArchivo(t);
            //Specification says that each reader
            //should wait a bit before trying to 
            //read the file again
            napTime = ran.nextInt(1000);
            t.sleep(napTime);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("InterruptedException");
        }


    }       
}
}

class Controler{
Random ran;
LinkedList <Reader> readers;

int n; 
int count; 

public Controler(int n){
    readers = new LinkedList <Reader>();
    this.n = n;
    count = 0;
    ran = new Random();

}

public synchronized void getPermission(){
    try{
        while(count >= n){
            wait(); 
        }   
        notify();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("InterruptedException");
    }   
}

public synchronized void increaseCount(){
    count++;
}

public synchronized void decreaseCount(){
    count--;
    System.out.println("There are " + count + " threads reading");
}


public void intentarLeerArchivo(Thread t){

    int readTime = 1000;
    try{
        getPermission();

        System.out.println("Thread " + t.getId() +" empezó a leer");
        increaseCount();
        t.sleep(readTime);

        System.out.println("Thread " + t.getId() +" is reading");

        System.out.println("Thread " + t.getId() + " finished reading");            
        decreaseCount();

    } catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("InterruptedException");
    }
}                       
}



class Initializer{

int numReaders;
int maxReaders;

public Initializer(int numReaders, int maxReaders){
    this.numReaders = numReaders;
    this.maxReaders = maxReaders;
}

public void init(){
    Controler c = new Controler(maxReaders);

    for(int i = 0; i < numReaders; i++){
        new Reader(c);
    }
}


}

public class FileShare{
public static void main(String [] args){
    Initializer c = new Initializer(100, 50);
    c.init();
}

}
```

There are a few lines I wrote in order to debug. They print the state of each thread and the number of threads that are reading whenever one of them ends reading. But when I run the program, it turns out that suddenly there are more Threads reading the file than the ones there were supposed to be doing so. I guess it has something to do with my synchronization manipulation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This could be an X/Y problem/re-inventing the wheel.  Java already contains a class that monitors a directory (including its files) for changes.  Consider using that class instead of trying to implement your own.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: I would do so, but i was asked to actually re-invent the wheel as an asignement.

Answer (score 0):

When a thread is in the

```
while(...){wait()}
```

section of your implementation, it wait until someone notify it to go on. Right now, when you finish waiting, you notify right away.

Think about it, if once I get in I notify someone to come, he will not wait until I'm done before coming in. You want to use notify when you leave the file.

Comment: Thanks! That was it!